# typescript No overload matches this call react.cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting a typescript error in my react code on my React.cloneElement first parameter "childred", which I don't understand.

I think that the type defined in index.d.ts for cloneElement don't apply to this case but i'm quite new to typescript, how could I fix it? What do the "P", "T" in index.d.ts stands for?

MessageType.tsx:

```
class MessageType extends React.Component<any, any> {

 [.....]

const { children, noFloating } = this.props ;

  [.....]


{messageType
              ? React.cloneElement(children, {
                  ...(noFloating ? {} : { floatingMessage }),
                  messageType,
                  message: `Example ${messageType} message`,
                })
              : children}
```

in this piece of code above "children" is red

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionComponentElement<P>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponentElement<P>'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(328, 14): The last overload is declared here.
```

index.d.ts:

```
/ Custom components
function cloneElement<P>(
    element: FunctionComponentElement<P>,
    props?: Partial<P> & Attributes,
    ...children: ReactNode[]): FunctionComponentElement<P>;
function cloneElement<P, T extends Component<P, ComponentState>>(
    element: CElement<P, T>,
    props?: Partial<P> & ClassAttributes<T>,
    ...children: ReactNode[]): CElement<P, T>;
function cloneElement<P>(
    element: ReactElement<P>,
    props?: Partial<P> & Attributes,
    ...children: ReactNode[]): ReactElement<P>;
```

Answer (score 3):

solved declaring :

```
children as React.ReactElement<any>
```

but I think there's a solution more correct